# \fmtversion not the same with xelatex and pdflatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, texlive, format-files

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fmtversion
\end{document}
```

Texlive 2015 was updated today (tmlgr update --all)

- The command:

  xelatex file.tex

creates a .pdf file which contains `2015/01/01`. The corresponding log file contains

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.11.4) .

- The command:

  pdflatex file.tex

creates a .pdf file which contains `2015/10/01`. The corresponding log file contains

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.11.4).

I thought tmlgr would update the xelatex and pdflatex programs when the latex.ltx file is updated. This does not seem to be the case?

I ask this question, because as (r)(e)ledmac tests the value of `\fmtversion` to determine where to load the `etex` package, it might produce an error (cf https://github.com/maieul/latexhumain/issues/44).

Comment: It seems to be a problem with TeX Live. I issued `sudo fmtutil-sys --byengine xetex` and after that I got `2015/10/01` from `\fmtversion`. Indeed, it was `2015/01/01` before running `fmtutil-sys`. Make this known to the `texlive` mailing list.

Comment: yes, it works. So it is an issue to report to the texlive team?

Comment: Yes; apparently the update to the LaTeX kernel didn't trigger format recreation for XeTeX.

Comment: As answered on the TL list, it is a problem only with xe(la)tex, as far as I see. pdflatex (and latex and cslatex etc etc) should all be updated automatically. If there is a problem with (pdf)latex formats itself, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in TeX Live scripts, which failed to trigger format creation after the last upgrades to the LaTeX kernel.

You can fix the thing manually by

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --byengine xetex --byfmt latex
```

Report the issue to the TeX Live mailing list.

---

### Update

According to the messages in the mailing list (starting from http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-November/037480.html), the issue should have been solved with [revision 38810](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=38810) of TeX Live.

Comment: done, I have send an email.

Comment: The `3.14159265-2.6-0.99992` is not supposed to change? Only the date?

Comment: @cfr That's the banner of the executable, which is independent of the format.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to be clear that I hadn't done something wrong.